# How to load Json Data into Select2

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2

I have faced a problem using select2 js,
This is my json respond

```
{"items":[{"name":"majid"}],"total_count":1,"incomplete_results":false}
```

And this is my javascript code

```
$(".js-example-data-ajax").select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    width: 250,
    //containerCssClass: 'bg-indigo-400',
    //dropdownCssClass: 'bg-indigo-400',
    //containerCssClass: 'select-lg',
    placeholder: "Select a State",
    allowClear: true,
    //tags: true,
    ajax: {
        url:'set',//'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',//'set',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            //alert(params.page);
            return {
                q: params.term//, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
            // scrolling can be used



            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    //escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    //templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    //templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
});
```

I don't know where is my mistake,I have read it's Examples but could not find any solutions,
Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select 2 accepts a specific JSON object structure i.e. -

```
var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];
```

In your case "items" key should contain an array of similar objects like `[{ id: 1, text: 'bug' }]` or you can modify the object before returning, like this -

```
var data = $.map(yourArrayData, function (obj) {
   obj.id = obj.id || obj.pk; // replace pk with your identifier
   return obj;
});
```

They have already added below comment in their example code.

```
processResults: function (data, params) { 
// parse the results into the format expected by Select2
```

See official docs - https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-array and read this as well https://select2.github.io/options.html#data.

Comment: Thank for your help.